# How do I return a redux state with a incremented or decremented value?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to return a state in redux that just increments/decrements a value.

The variable I am trying to increment looks like this:

```
state = {
     posts = [
        {title: 'bla', id: '123', value: 1},
        {title: 'bla2' , id: '321' value: 2},
        {title: 'bla3', id: '135' value: 3}
     ]
}
```

from the actions I dispatch I have the ID of the object I want to increment. So this is what I tried:

```
state.map(post => {
        if(post.id === action.id){
          let newCount = post.value - 1;
          return {
            ...post,
            value: newCount
          }
        }
      })
```

But it's not working and I am not sure how to solve this.

---

Just so you all know, I just had to return it an use and else statement to return the post if I could not find the id.

looks like this:

```
return state.map(post => {
        if(post.id === action.parentId){
          let newCount = post.commentCount - 1;
          return {
            ...post,
            commentCount: newCount
          }
        }
        else{
          return post;
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear if you just didn't include all the code, or if that's the code as-is. Just running `map` won't do anything at all to the state; you should probably provide a bit more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this fix the issue?

```
let result = state.posts.map(post => {
        if(post.id === action.id){
          let newCount = post.value - 1;
          return {
            ...post,
            value: newCount
          }
        } 
        return post; // handle this case too
      })
```

This will correctly update the element with given `id` in `state` in immutable way - so you need to assign the result to something and use it later as in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
state.posts.map(post => {
```

instead of:

```
state.map(post => {
```

Because you must iterate on the posts Array instead of the state Object

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the posts and then return the new state object like this:

```
case UPDATE_POST_COUNT:
  let updatedPosts = state.posts.map(post => {
        if(post.id === action.id){
          let newCount = post.value - 1;
          return {
            ...post,
            value: newCount
          }
        } 
        return post; // handle this case too
      })
   // now construct the new state object
   return Object.assign({}, state, {posts: updatedPosts})
```